# How can I request parameters via ajax in Symfony?

Tags: php, json, ajax, symfony

I want to make an ajax request that sends a variable, in my case `length` to another

This is the ajax request:

```
  var length = 5;

  $.ajax({
    method:'POST',
    data: {
      "id": id,
      "length": length,
      "start": start,
    },
    url:'{{ path('json', { 'fileName': output.fileName }) }}',
    success : function (data) {
       alert("success");
  }
```

Controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/_json/{fileName}", name="json", methods={"GET","POST"})
 */
public function jsonGenerator(JsonGenerator $jsonGenerator, $fileName)
{
    $output = $jsonGenerator->getJson($fileName);

    return $output;
}
```

Then my class:

```
class jsonGenerator
{
    public function __construct(
        EntityManagerInterface $em, 
        ClassMetadataFactoryInterface $classMetadataFactory = null, 
        NameConverterInterface $nameConverter = null, 
        PropertyAccessorInterface $propertyAccessor = null, 
        PropertyTypeExtractorInterface $propertyTypeExtractor = null, 
        ClassDiscriminatorResolverInterface $classDiscriminatorResolver = null, 
        callable $objectClassResolver = null, 
        array $defaultContext = []
    ){
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function getJson($fileName)
    {
        if (isset($request)) {
            $length = $request->request->get('length');
        } else {
            $length = 10;
        }

        $file = 'files/'.$fileName.'.json';

        $input = file_get_contents($file);
        $array = json_decode($input);

        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            if ('data' == $key) {
                $new = \array_slice($value, 0, length);
            }
        }

        $array->data = $new;

        $output = json_encode($array);

        return new Response($output);
    }
}
```

My problem is, that my request is not going through.
The length stays always 10, but I expect the output to have the length 5.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You do actually need to inject the request into the function. Your length is always 10 because `if(isset($request)){` is always not set. Your function should look more like this `public function jsonGenerator($fileName, Request $request, JsonGenerator $jsonGenerator) {` and ofc you need to pass on the `$request` to the called function down the line.

Comment: @Andrei I changed it as you recommended to `public function jsonGenerator(JsonGenerator $jsonGenerator, Request $request, $fileName) {` but still the length is 10.

Comment: Did you also pass the request down the line to `$jsonGenerator->getJson($fileName);`?

Comment: Do you mean like this: `$jsonGenerator->getJson($fileName,length);`?

Comment: No. No, I don't mean that. Perhaps you should review the basics of functions and such in PHP. This seems more of a basic understanding of coding rather than an actual problem. You have a variable in X scope and you want it in Y scope of function Z. You must pass variable X to function Z via it's parameters.

Comment: Ah no, I think it should be like this `public function jsonGenerator(JsonGenerator $jsonGenerator, Request $request, $fileName) {    $length = $request->request->get('length');
$output = $jsonGenerator->getJson($fileName,$length);`

Comment: yes, this worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your **Class** and **method**

`public function getJson($fileName)`

try to do this

`public function getJson($fileName, Request $request)`

Comment: The answer is `public function jsonGenerator(JsonGenerator $jsonGenerator, Request $request, $fileName) { $length = $request->request->get('length'); $output = $jsonGenerator->getJson($fileName,$length);`